# Геокодирование с помощью Google Geocoding на украинском языке

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

Адрес на украинском языке формата: "51100 Дніпропетровська Магдалинівський Магдалинівка пров. Жовтневий буд. 6" - не находит.

на русском: "51100 Днепропетровская Магдалиновский Магдалиновка пер. Жовтневий д. 6" - Находит

Если этот же адрес ввести на Google Maps на украинском языке - находит
Как можно геокодировать адреса на украинском языке?

```
$address = "51100 Дніпропетровська Магдалинівський Магдалинівка пров. Жовтневий буд. 6";    
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml? 
address='.$address.'&language=uk');
$status = $xml->status;
```

Получаю "ZERO_RESULTS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в запрос `language=uk`

Полный список поддерживаемых языков [здесь](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=ru#languagesupport)

**Update** замените в запросе `буд.` на `б.` и будет вам [счастье](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=51100%20%D0%94%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2.%20%D0%96%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%206&language=uk)